# How to disable multiarch support?

Tags: package-management, multiarch

I don't want to install any i386 package.
Is there any way to disable functionality?

Comment: [How to remove all i386 packages from Ubuntu 64bit?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/113301/how-to-remove-all-i386-packages-from-ubuntu-64bit)

Answer (score 64):

### Since 12.10

```
dpkg --remove-architecture i386
```

to get rid of multiarch on an amd64 installation. In case you will have message, like:

```
dpkg: error: cannot remove architecture 'i386' currently in use by the database
```

you should remove all `i386` packages before:

```
dpkg -l | grep i386
```

Comment: With the regex feature of apt-get, you can `apt-get remove .*:i386`

Comment: or: sudo aptitude purge '~i ~ri386'

Answer (score 17):

### 11.10 & 12.04

Multiarch support is enabled by the file `/etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch`

If you rename this file and run an update in a terminal you will notice that the i386 repo's are no longer visible.

Thus

```
sudo mv /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch.backup
```

Answer (score 14):

Based on both [Ben's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/256495/40030) and [user41220's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/189690/40030) I did the following:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge `dpkg --get-selections | grep i386 | awk '{print $1}'`
```

Then

```
sudo dpkg --remove-architecture i386
```

and that worked just fine for me.

Comment: I see no additional information than existing answers.

Answer (score 13):

First of all, remove all i386-packages like so:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge `dpkg --get-selections | grep i386 | awk '{print $1}'`
```

Please note: Skype, Steam, teamviewer etc. might be purged as well.

Then proceed with fossfreedoms advices.

Comment: This is true for more recent oses. If you put this in as an answer, I'd vote for it (for its simplicity).

Answer (score 1):

Simpler alternative to remove all packages of that architecture before removing it ([source](https://askubuntu.com/a/873064/349837); [`apt` man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man8/apt.8.html)):

```
sudo apt purge .*:i386
```

If necessary (check with [`dpkg --print-foreign-architectures`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/dpkg.1.html)) you can remove the architecture from dpkg:

```
sudo dpkg --remove-architecture i386
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who want to disable multiarch support from the get-go, here's a one liner that can be used in (init) scripts...

```
[ ! $(dpkg --get-selections | grep -q i386) ] && dpkg --remove-architecture i386
```

This would remove i386 architechture as expected on the first run. On consecutive runs, it'd show the following warning...

> dpkg: warning: cannot remove non-foreign architecture 'i386'

This one-liner could be useful in most cloud servers where there are no i386 packages are installed (by default). While this is a Ubuntu forum, here is some detailed info on multiarch from Debian... https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO .

Other answers recommended `dpkg -l` to get the list of packages and then `grep` the result. In my experience, `dpkg -l` has failed to show some packages (with i386 arch), but `dpkg --get-selections` showed them clearly marking them as `package_name:i386`. So, if we want to remove i386 packages previous installed, then to remove them, here's actual command that works...

```
apt-get remove --purge `dpkg --get-selections | awk '/i386/{print $1}'`
```