# How to remove all i386 packages from Ubuntu 64bit?

Tags: package-management, 64-bit, uninstall, 32-bit

Over the time I installed many i386 packages, which I no longer need. How can I clean up the system and stay only with the amd64 packages?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/66875/how-to-disable-multiarch-support

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If they are not in your way, I would leave them where they are.

If you insist on deletion, use `dpkg -l | grep i386` to create a list of i386-packages. You can delete these after **careful checking** with something like `sudo apt-get purge <package-name>`.

Comment: Except that aptitude is [broken on multiarch](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/aptitude/+bug/831768), so that won't work so well :P

Comment: `apt-get purge <package-name>` should still work, though.

Comment: "after careful checking" -- that is vague.  Please be more clear.

Comment: i have a i386 system on a usb sometimes i use it on amd64 machines ,  now i just wanted to do the inverse , so after running `dpkg -l | grep amd64` i got an i386 pkg in my list which is `amd64-microcode                              3.20160316.3                           i386` , i  think that the ':' in the grep pattern is important ! (`dpkg -l | grep ":amd64"`)

Answer (score 42):

The other automated solutions are dangerous and not always working (1), so here another way

```
sudo aptitude purge `dpkg --get-selections | grep ":i386" | awk '{print $1}'`
```

or

```
sudo apt-get purge `dpkg --get-selections | grep ":i386" | awk '{print $1}'`
```

(Try to use always and only one of the tools. Since aptitude is better when having dependency trouble, I prefer that.)

Good idea to also

```
dpkg --remove-architecture i386
```

and maybe

```
dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
```

(1) The other commands also lists packages having only i386 in their name (although they are for 64bit architecture), the regular expression didn't work and dpkg shows packages which are already removed, but still have configuration files left (*dpkg -l*  shows "rc" instead of "ii" as status).

Comment: Since you're using `awk` anyway, you may as well get rid of the `grep` invocation. Also, `$()` is preferable instead of backticks. I just got rid of my i386 packages using this command based on the one you gave: `sudo apt purge $(dpkg --get-selections | awk '$1 ~ /:i386$/ { print $1 }')`

Comment: The aptitude one works correctly.

Comment: This will break your Steam client, even if you installed the client for amd64 architecture, it still installs some 32-bit files and libraries to ensure compatibility with older games.

Answer (score 24):

I blitzed all my 32bit packages like this:

```
sudo apt-get remove `dpkg --get-selections | grep i386 | awk '{print $1}'`
```

Comment: how to make these kind of commands, i know apt-get and grep but whats awk'{print $1}', just want to know.

Comment: awesome, and I was able to remove the i386 architecture now, but when I do `dpkg -l | grep i386` to check the packages are still there any ideas, also +1 for the previouse comment and my guess it's related to shell scripting techniques

Comment: No responses probably because comments aren't the place for an awk tutorial. That bit of awk is printing only the first field of each line being piped in. Awk's default field separator is a space, " ".

Comment: Finish it off with `sudo dpkg --remove-architecture i386`

Answer (score 16):

The [debian's multiarch guide](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO) mentions this command: `apt-get purge ".*:<arch>"`, which would look like this for `i386`:

```
sudo apt-get purge ".*:i386"
```

You can then remove the architecture from dpkg:

```
sudo dpkg --remove-architecture i386
```

Answer (score 10):

In case anyone is wondering, there's a much more sane and graceful way to do this. The last previous answer hopes to do the same thing, but that search fails since architectures are not actually part of package names, except in special cases.

as root (or with sudo) run:

```
aptitude remove ~i~ri386
```

If you don't use aptitude over apt-get already, do. It's really excellent. You can find a list of aptitude's search terms [here](http://aptitude.alioth.debian.org/doc/en/ch02s04s05.html).

Answer (score 6):

There is another way of lower risk:

```
sudo apt-get remove "^.*:i386$"
```

This will specifically match only packages ending with `":i386"`, which is the standard naming convention for all `i386` architecture Debian packages.

Comment: why remove over purge?

Comment: @Lotus: I am unaware of the difference.  Can you please explain?  Maybe we can update this answer to improve it.

Comment: purge takes the configuration files also and any remant directories iirc

Comment: @Lotus I used purge and it worked on 14.04.  This only worked for me after removing the quotation marks and carret.  `sudo apt-get purge .*:i386`