# Ubuntu 12.04 - Steam not running

Tags: installation, steam

I've been using Steam on Linux for quite a while now and never had any problems. Recently though, in the past few days, Steam seems not to start anymore- or at least, I can't see it running and I can't access any of my games.
I tried reinstalling it, but to no avail.

If I try to run "steam" in terminal, this is what I get:

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 12.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
```

and then nothing happens.

If I try opening it with `STEAM_RUNTIME=0 steam`, I get:

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 12.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is disabled by the user

Error: You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run:

libpangoft2-1.0.so.0
libpango-1.0.so.0
libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0
libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0
libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0
libpangocairo-1.0.so.0
libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0
libcairo.so.2
libpango-1.0.so.0
libnss3.so
libnssutil3.so
libsmime3.so
libplc4.so
libnspr4.so
```

So I'm quite at a loss as to what has happened here. I haven't changed anything in my configuration, and I'm not even sure where to find such libraries.

What can I do, since a removal and a reinstall didn't work?

Small update: I tried opening Playonlinux (my WoW installation stopped working now too), and I received an error message that basically said I no longer had any 32bit libraries and that my games could not run properly.
So now the question is- how do I get them back? :)

SECOND UPDATE: I tried reinstalling the ia32-libs, and this is the outcome:

```
    sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
    requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
    distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
    or been moved out of Incoming.
    The following information may help to resolve the situation:

    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     ia32-libs : Depends: ia32-libs-multiarch
    E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So then I tried running sudo apt-get install ia32-libs-multiarch , and I got this:

```
    Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
    requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
    distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
    or been moved out of Incoming.
    The following information may help to resolve the situation:

    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     ia32-libs-multiarch:i386 : Depends: gstreamer0.10-plugins-good:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: gtk2-engines:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: gtk2-engines-murrine:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: gtk2-engines-pixbuf:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: gtk2-engines-oxygen:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: ibus-gtk:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libcanberra-gtk-module:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libgail-common:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libgtk2.0-0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: librsvg2-common:i386 but it is not going to be installed
    E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I think it's pretty obvious at this point that my 32libs are either gone or no longer recognized, but I have no idea why.

Comment: @Braiam Ok, I've deleted my comment because the other one is indeed less detailed. However : He is using an 64bit Ubuntu. The apt-get you provide will install 64bit libraries, not 32bits ...

Comment: Could you tell us why your tried to install the 32-bits libraries? Or, more like, what were the exact commands so we can revert back and pull you from that dependency problem.

Comment: I am having exactly the same issue. I am running Ubuntu 13.04 64-bit.

Comment: You are using a PPA that has an outdated ia32-libs-multiarch. Do a apt-cache show ia32-libs-multiarch to know the ppa that provide the package and try to find another one that is newer. If you want to use the @Braiam solution you need to remove the 32bit libs that you have installed. If you don't know then you must remove them all (at your own risk - It's quite dangerous if your ubuntu has some life - do a backup). If you still want to do it then follow this thread to remove the 32 bit : http://askubuntu.com/questions/113301/how-to-remove-all-i386-packages-from-ubuntu-64bit

Answer (score 0):

Somehow either you have missing libraries or Steam don't know where they are. You can solve the first by running:

```
sudo apt-get install libpango-1.0-0 libpangoft2-1.0-0 libgtk2.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libcairo2 libnss3-1d libnss3 libnspr4-0d
```

Once you have done this, try again.

Comment: Apparently, none of these packages can be found.

Comment: @user193143 did you ran `sudo apt-get update` before hand?

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this issue as well. I had steam relocated to a ntfs formatted drive to be read by Windows. I had symbolicaly linked ~/.local/share/Steam to the other folder and I think that was the issue. I put the Steam files back and only linked the SteamApps folder and then it worked fine.