# Risky to remove all i386 packages on a 64-bits install?

Tags: 64-bit, multiarch

I don't use any 32-bits app on my 64-bits Vivid so i want to remove all i386 packages but I wonder if this can be done safely. Thx for help !

Edit : Here's the return from the 'dpkg -l | grep i386' command > http://paste.ubuntu.com/11118173/

Comment: First you shoud make a list of installed 32bit apps: `dpkg -l | grep i386`. If you [add](http://askubuntu.com/posts/623308/edit) the result to your question, we may help you in your decision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes they are some risk.
You should first read this post : [How to remove all i386 packages from Ubuntu 64bit?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/113301/how-to-remove-all-i386-packages-from-ubuntu-64bit)

As Henk say, if they are not in your way, I would leave them where they are.

Comment: You've probably right, I'll leave that as it is to avoid problems. But to satisfy my curiosity, I will try to do this on a virtual machine.

Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

Your question can not be answered with absolute certainty.

Have you installed Steam and/or Skype? Then you should watch out. These programs use 32-bit libraries.

Your list contains only packages that have been installed by the package manager. Make much broken, you can not. Libraries can be installed again.

Apart from, your list itself contains nothing that could not be removed safely on a 64-bit system. If there still should be a problem, you will previously warned by the package manager.

You could use `aptitude`:

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
```

And run with

```
sudo aptitude remove <package_name>
```

Eg.

```
sudo aptitude remove libasound2-plugins:i386
```

This program also immediately remove packages that are no longer needed. In addition, this program provides useful solutions if something goes wrong.