# Why are i386 packages automatically installed on a 64bit machine?

Tags: software-installation, 64-bit, 32-bit

I run Trusty Desktop on a 64 bit machine, so if I query installed packages, e.g.:

```
$ dpkg-query -l gcc* | grep 'ii '
ii  gcc                      4:4.8.2-1ubuntu6        amd64        GNU C compiler
ii  gcc-4.8                  4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04    amd64        GNU C compiler
ii  gcc-4.8-base:amd64       4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04    amd64        GCC, the GNU Compiler Collection (base package)
ii  gcc-4.8-base:i386        4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04    i386         GCC, the GNU Compiler Collection (base package)
ii  gcc-4.8-doc              4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04    all          Documentation for the GNU compilers (gcc, gobjc, g++)
ii  gcc-4.8-multilib         4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04    amd64        GNU C compiler (multilib files)
ii  gcc-4.9-base:amd64       4.9.1-0ubuntu1          amd64        GCC, the GNU Compiler Collection (base package)
ii  gcc-4.9-base:i386        4.9.1-0ubuntu1          i386         GCC, the GNU Compiler Collection (base package)
```

why do I see those i386 installed packages ? I have 118 of them on that particular install... Is it that some dependencies for amd64 packages are satisfied by some i386 packages ? Is it something else ? Does the OS need them ?

**Note**: I am really asking "*why are they here?*" not "*how do I get rid of them?*". The [latter question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/113301/how-to-remove-all-i386-packages-from-ubuntu-64bit) is well covered.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install aptitude; aptitude why gcc-4.8-base:i386`

Comment: IIRC the particular ones mentioned are needed for gcc to build i386 binaries on x86_64 i.e. to support the `-m32` compiler flag. As such, they are probably there because `gcc-multilib` is installed: however, I don't recally `gcc-multilib` being installed *automatically* (it is only a *suggested* package for gcc) - I can't answer that part.

Comment: @steeldriver: +1. Yes, I did install gcc-multilib as an option (suggested package). Really interesting but this was just a handy example. Are you saying that the presence of other such packages correspond to the same logic?  Namely that i386 installed packages derive from optional or suggested packages installs ? Not from the main base x86_64 packages ?

Comment: @A.B.: installing aptitude now. Finally. Will report.

Comment: @A.B.: This is IT ! Please, can you formulate a short answer so I can mark it as accepted ? `aptitude` is oddly great. Had heard about it quite a bit but for me `synaptic` from the gui was good enough.  I don't think I will look back.  cli rules.

Comment: @Cbhihe I wouldn't feel comfortable generalizing about that: I'm only (vaguely) familiar with gcc-multilib and friends (g++-multilib, gfortran-multilib)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple command gives you the necessary information. But first you have to install a nifty tool:

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
```

Now check with e.g.:

```
aptitude why gcc-4.8-base:i386
```

Comment: As it turns out,  executing `aptitude why gcc-4.8-base:i386` in terminal  throws `i skype` (amd64) and  `i A skype-bin:i386` back. But then checking reverse dependencies for installed packages with `sudo apt-cache rdepends --installed gcc-4.8-base:i386` in terminal yields nothing related to skype....  0_o ? How should I interpret the result of  `aptitude why gcc-4.8-base:i386` ?

Comment: You have to follow up the dependency tree.