# Help me fix dependencies at sudo apt-get -f install failure

Tags: package-management, software-installation, dpkg, network-manager, dependencies

So I was having some problems with my network manager and I tried to reinstall it as it wouldn't work at all.

Fast forward a few packages later and now the network manager and network work but I have no icon, on the top right side, with the networks. I have [this error icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3cRi.png) with the erorr message :

> "Error: BrokenCount>0".

Following the instructions provided doesn't solve the problem as I still get the error as bellow.

The Ubuntu Software installer doesn't work as well. When I try to install/update something it just loads a little and then stops as if I canceled.

If someone could solve this one I would be thankful.

```
sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 aptitude:i386 : Depends: libapt-pkg4.12:i386 (>= 0.8.16~exp12ubuntu6) but it is not installable
             Depends: libboost-iostreams1.46.1:i386 (>= 1.46.1-1) but it is not installable
             Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installed
             Depends: libcwidget3:i386 but it is not installable
             Depends: libept1.4.12:i386 but it is not installable
             Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not installed
             Depends: libncursesw5:i386 (>= 5.6+20070908) but it is not installed
             Depends: libsigc++-2.0-0c2a:i386 (>= 2.0.2) but it is not installable
             Depends: libsqlite3-0:i386 (>= 3.6.5) but it is not installed
             Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 4.6) but it is not installed
             Depends: libtinfo5:i386 but it is not installed
             Depends: libxapian22:i386 but it is not installable
             Recommends: apt-xapian-index:i386 but it is not installable
             Recommends: libparse-debianchangelog-perl:i386 but it is not installable
 libnl-genl-3-200 : Depends: libnl-3-200 (= 3.2.27-1ubuntu0.16.04.1) but 3.2.29-0ubuntu2.1 is installed
 libnspr4:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.17) but it is not installed
 ppa-purge : Depends: aptitude
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies`
```

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` . Why are you running `apt-get install -f` did you install a package with dpkg ?

Comment: Yes, I did install a package with dpkg but I can't remember which. If I run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` I get this : [link](https://textsaver.flap.tv/lists/1ncq)

Comment: You can try removing your i386 packages - https://askubuntu.com/questions/113301/how-to-remove-all-i386-packages-from-ubuntu-64bit .