# i386 preventing installing Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04

I want to install Ubuntu 20.04 but I apparently have i386 architecture. How should I proceed?

Comment: What do you mean by "I have i386 architecture". If your CPU is 32-bit only, you can't install Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: I was quoting the message I got when I tried to update to 20.04. I am obviously in over my head here.

Comment: So what is your hardware?

Comment: I don't know how to determine that

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what you are trying to do and what is the hardware you are using. Now the question is very unclear.

Comment: see "Upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04 fails on i386 packages"

Comment: "I don't know how to determine that". Call "cat /proc/cpuinfo"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04 fails on i386 packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1257534/upgrade-to-ubuntu-20-04-fails-on-i386-packages)