# apt-get update fails complaining about architecture 1386

Tags: apt, package-management, architecture

When I run `sudo apt-get update` I get this error with many packages:

```
Omitiendo el uso del fichero configurado «main/binary-1386/Packages»
  ya que el repositorio «http : //bo.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease»
  no admite la arquitectura «1386»
```

I think the problem started when I tried to install Skype and one step was:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

That gave me this result

```
Odd number of elements in hash assignment at /usr/share/pkg-config-dpkghook line 30.
```

I used this [How to install Skype on Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial Xerus Linux 64-bit | LinuxConfig.org](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-skype-on-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-linux-64-bit)

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64-bit

How can I fix this problem?

[image: This is what appears when I put sudo apt-get update or sudo apt-get update --fix-missing]

Comment: Can you translate `Omitiendo el uso del fichero configurado «main/binary-1386/Packages» ya que el repositorio «http://bo.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease» no admite la arquitectura «1386»` into English?

Comment: My English is not good but it will be:

> Omitting the use of the configured file  «main/binary-1386/Packages» since the repository «http://bo.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease» not support the architecture «1386»

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to solve "Unable to find expected entry 'restricted/binary-1386/Packages' Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/383644/how-to-solve-unable-to-find-expected-entry-restricted-binary-1386-packages-wr)

Answer (score 3):

Didn't you just misread/mistype the command and added an "1386" architecture instead of an "i386"? If so you should be able to remove that architecture with

```
sudo sudo dpkg --remove-architecture 1386
```

and then add the proper i386 architecture:

```
sudo sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

(this architecture is possibly already there anyway)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works.
I understand what it means know