# Failed to download repository information (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

Tags: apt, updates

I get the following error log while trying to update packages list:

```
Failed to download repository information
Check your Internet connection.
W:Failed to fetch http://ftp.wcss.pl/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/InRelease  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-aarch64/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
W:Failed to fetch http://ftp.wcss.pl/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/InRelease  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-aarch64/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
W:Failed to fetch http://ftp.wcss.pl/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/InRelease  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-aarch64/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
W:Failed to fetch http://ftp.wcss.pl/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-aarch64/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
W:Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-aarch64/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Tried `apt-get clean` and `autoclean`, [changing servers](https://askubuntu.com/a/766176), even [removing architecture](https://askubuntu.com/a/576155) (but dpkg said I can't because it's in use by the database). Also tried to remove the line containing the problematic entries but my sources.list does not contain them. When I do `cat /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*` this is what I get:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140722.2)]/ trusty main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://ftp.wcss.pl/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
deb-src http://ftp.wcss.pl/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://ftp.wcss.pl/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
deb-src http://ftp.wcss.pl/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://ftp.wcss.pl/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb-src http://ftp.wcss.pl/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb http://ftp.wcss.pl/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
deb-src http://ftp.wcss.pl/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://ftp.wcss.pl/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb-src http://ftp.wcss.pl/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb http://ftp.wcss.pl/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
deb-src http://ftp.wcss.pl/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://ftp.wcss.pl/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://ftp.wcss.pl/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://ftp.wcss.pl/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted
deb-src http://ftp.wcss.pl/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted
deb http://ftp.wcss.pl/ubuntu/ trusty-security universe
deb-src http://ftp.wcss.pl/ubuntu/ trusty-security universe
deb http://ftp.wcss.pl/ubuntu/ trusty-security multiverse
deb-src http://ftp.wcss.pl/ubuntu/ trusty-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Ubuntu's
## 'extras' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
# deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb file:///var/cuda-repo-7-0-local /
deb file:///var/cuda-repo-7-0-local /
deb http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1404/x86_64 /
deb http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1404/x86_64 /
deb [arch=i386,amd64] http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb [arch=i386,amd64] http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted universe multiverse
# deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu1404/x86_64 /
deb http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu1404/x86_64 /
```

This is also different than the [suggested duplicate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78951) - my error log does not contain an index of the corrupted line. Actually, my `sources.list` does not even contain entries similar to the ones mentioned in the message.

What can I do with it?

Comment: I think problem is that you are trying to access ftp servers by http protocol and in several last records. Try to set the server to default and remove everything under extras repo.

Comment: @Danatela I followed the answer below and changed server to main via http - errors persist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to this error:

```
 Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-aarch64/Packages'
```

You have added `aarch64` architecture, but the repositories have no packages for that architecture.

Check:

```
dpkg --print-architecture
```

and

```
dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
```

You should see `aarch64` in foreign architectures. Remove it:

```
dpkg --remove-architecture aarch64
```

If you get this error:

```
error: cannot remove architecture 'aarch64' currently in use by the database
```

You will have to remove any `aarch64` packages you have:

```
dpkg -l | grep aarch64
```

Remove anything you find (with `sudo apt remove`)

And try updating again.

Alternatively, **if you need those packages**, keep the foreign architecture, and configure each line in your sources list that throws errors to search only for packages from the architectures you want, by adding `[ arch=amd64 ]` or `[ arch=i386,amd64 ]` like this, for example:

```
deb [ arch=amd64 ] http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main
```

Comment: Tried that and got the same error but with archive.ubuntu.com instead of ftp.wcss.pl in the error logs.

Comment: @PrzemekD ah! it's the architecture... you have added arm64 architecture but those repositories do not contain any arm64 packages. Do you need arm64 architecture?

Comment: I as a user do not. Does ubuntu? dpkg gave me a following warning: cannot remove non-foreign architecture 'arm64'

Comment: @PrzemekD what's the output of `dpkg --print-architecture` and `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures` ?

Comment: `--print-architecture` returns only `amd64`, while `--print-foreign-architectures` gives `i386, aarch64, armhf`. Should I remove the ARM one?

Comment: @PrzemekD remove `aarch64`, that's the one causing trouble. If you still get an error, remove `armhf` as well

Comment: `warning: cannot remove non-foreign architecture 'aamd64'`, `error: cannot remove architecture 'armhf' currently in use by the database`. By the way, how do you know it's that?

Comment: @PrzemekD from the error message (see updated answer) you made a typo, it is not `aamd64` it's `aarch64`

Comment: I'm sorry, so stupid of me. Corrected: `error: cannot remove architecture 'aarch64' currently in use by the database`

Comment: @PrzemekD that means you have packages from the architecture, so you have to remove them first. Try `dpkg -l | grep aarch64` and remove any packages you find (this is weird though... where did they come from?)

Comment: I forced removal of everything remotely related to `aarch64` and `armhf` then removed them from dpkg; for now nothing exploded and the updates are proceeding. But what if I needed to have these packages? I might need to reinstall them in the future (since they are a part of Nvidia Jetson developer package, I think) - should I expect the whole system to break down again or is there any way ubuntu can work with them on board?

Comment: @PrzemekD see my edit - if you really need those packages, you can add the architecture, but configure the lines in the sources.list that throw errors to look only for the correct architectures