# Accidentally added architecture 1386 instead of i386

Tags: 20.04, package-management, dpkg

When installing wine on my Ubuntu machine, I made a small typo when allowing for 32-bit and 64-bit systems. I accidentally typed `sudo dpkg --add-architecture 1386` instead of `i386`.

Now, when I try to `sudo apt-get update` or install any new software, I eventually get (among others) two noticeable error messages. The first is:

```
404 IP [some strange number, not my IP address] not found
```

The second error message ends with:

```
architecture 1386 not supported
```

I believe this is a result of the typo that I made using the `dpkg` command. How can I undo this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve "Unable to find expected entry 'restricted/binary-1386/Packages' Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/383644/how-to-solve-unable-to-find-expected-entry-restricted-binary-1386-packages-wr)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can just undo `--add-architecture` with `--remove-architecture`.

Dpkg maintains a list of architectures it is supposed to track, apt consumes this list and tries to fetch package lists for each of them.