# Why is my ubuntu trying to fetch aarch64 packages on x86_64 system

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, 64-bit, update-manager

I am unable to update my Ubuntu repositories. The command **apt-get update** gives following errors

```
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/InRelease  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-aarch64/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/hugin/hugin-builds/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-aarch64/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
W: Failed to fetch https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable/dists/stable/InRelease  Unable to find expected entry 'non-free/binary-aarch64/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
W: Failed to fetch https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian/dists/jessie/InRelease Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-aarch64/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/rabbitvcs/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-aarch64/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-aarch64/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead
```

This is my **sources.list** file

```
###### Ubuntu Main Repos
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main universe multiverse  
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main universe multiverse 

###### Ubuntu Update Repos
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main universe multiverse
```

**EDIT:**

This is the output of **dpkg --print-foreign-architectures**

```
i386
aarch64
armhf
```

Comment: Add the output of `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures`, please.

Comment: @muru I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"aarch64" is listed as a foreign architecture. This is not an architecture name in ubuntu. Open a terminal and run:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge `dpkg --get-selections | grep aarch64 | awk '{print $1}'`
sudo dpkg --remove-architecture aarch64.
```

Comment: it gives following warning 
dpkg: error: cannot remove architecture 'aarch64' currently in use by the database

Comment: Does this return results? `dpkg --get-selections | grep aarch64 | awk '{print $1}'`

Comment: Yeah I followed this link https://askubuntu.com/questions/66875/how-to-disable-multiarch-support to remove aarch64 packages which were installed. Then i was able to remove aarch64 architecture and updated the repositories successfully